# How can I show the review form?

Tags: magento2

Now I want to turn off the review form as shown in the image. When I click on the word Be the first to review this product, the review form appears, what should I do?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the "Be the first to review this product" link, you might need to modify your theme's template files. This involves creating a custom theme or overriding the existing templates.

Copy the file vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/product/review.phtml to your theme directory. If the file doesn't exist in your theme, copy it from the base theme.

Remove or comment out the code responsible for displaying the review link. Look for code similar to the following:

```
<a href="#" id="review-add-link">
    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Be the first to review this product')) ?>
</a>
```

After making changes, clear the Magento cache to apply the modifications.

Run the following command in the Magento root directory:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```